# create-react-app in shared folders in virtualbox debian not working - symlinks error

Tags: linux, reactjs, symlink, create-react-app

I have installed Debian 9 in VirtualBox on windows 10, and I have shared folders so I can access projects on Linux with the editor on windows.
I have installed nodejs, npm and create-react-app for react projects. Create-react-app was installed in non-shared folders, but when I have to make a new project I have to go to shared folders so that I can have access from windows to react app I created with create-react-app.

But I keep getting an error, for symlink, I have installed npm with no-bin links command, I have also tried everything I have found on StackOverflow and other places. So if someone had the same problem did he fixed it?

I am using php laravel for building API, and I need to use react for frontend, so if someone has maybe some other solutions to use react so I can normally work with windows and virtual machine and shared folders. It doesn't have to be create-react-app, but that seems to me like a good and fast solution to create react app. But I will accept any other solutions to get react work with shared folders.

Below is the error.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path ../acorn/bin/acorn
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/media/sf_debianShared/frontend/test/node_modules/.bin/acorn'
npm ERR! rofs This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! rofs and is related to the file system being read-only.
npm ERR! rofs
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /media/sf_debianShared/frontend/test/npm-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... npm-debug.log
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting test / from /media/sf_debianShared/frontend
Done.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's  not recommendable to work with windows folders, there is no solution for this. You must to create your folders in debian and trough samba shared with windows, it's more slow

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders
"Starting with version 4.0, VirtualBox shared folders also support symbolic links (symlinks), under the following conditions:

The host operating system must support symlinks (i.e. a Mac, Linux or Solaris host is required)."

Comment: Thanks, for now, I am working with NFS, but it gets stuck sometimes and from time to time is asking permissions in the editor, but its only solution for now. But I will try on Linux virtual machine install Docker, and through docker try to setup react, so that Linux is accessing docker image. But anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: did you solved it? anyway if you think is ok, you can accept the answer like valid